# LLenar un Select a través de un json

Tags: html, jquery, json, select

Hola amigos estoy tranado de llenar un select con lo siguiente, pero todos mis objetos me salen en undefined, ya intenté con Json.parse() pero nada

este es mi code

```js
< script >

  $(document).ready(function() {
    const temp = [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Aguascalientes"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Baja California"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Baja California Sur"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Campeche"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Coahuila"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Colima"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Chiapas"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Chihuahua"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Distrito Federal"
      },
      {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Durango"
      },
      {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Guanajuato"
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Guerrero"
      },
      {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Hidalgo"
      },
      {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Jalisco"
      },
      {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "México"
      },
      {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "Michoacán"
      },
      {
        "id": 17,
        "name": "Morelos"
      },
      {
        "id": 18,
        "name": "Nayarit"
      },
      {
        "id": 19,
        "name": "Nuevo León"
      },
      {
        "id": 20,
        "name": "Oaxaca"
      },
      {
        "id": 21,
        "name": "Puebla"
      },
      {
        "id": 22,
        "name": "Querétaro"
      },
      {
        "id": 23,
        "name": "Quintana Roo"
      },
      {
        "id": 24,
        "name": "San Luis Potosí"
      },
      {
        "id": 25,
        "name": "Sinaloa"
      },
      {
        "id": 26,
        "name": "Sonora"
      },
      {
        "id": 27,
        "name": "Tabasco"
      },
      {
        "id": 28,
        "name": "Tamaulipas"
      },
      {
        "id": 29,
        "name": "Tlaxcala"
      },
      {
        "id": 30,
        "name": "Veracruz"
      },
      {
        "id": 31,
        "name": "Yucatán"
      },
      {
        "id": 32,
        "name": "Zacatecas"
      }
    ];
    var $select = $('#estados');

    //alert(options);
    $.each(temp, function(id, name) {
      $select.append('<option value=' + temp.id + '>' + temp.name + '</option>');
    });
  }); <
/script>
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <select name="estados" id="estados"></select>


</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La funcion `each()` no funciona como piensas.  En tu ejemplo, la variable `name` representa cada uno de los objetos de tu array.  Por lo tanto, podrias hacerlo asi:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    const temp = [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Aguascalientes"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Baja California"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Baja California Sur"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Campeche"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Coahuila"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Colima"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Chiapas"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Chihuahua"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Distrito Federal"
      },
      {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Durango"
      },
      {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Guanajuato"
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Guerrero"
      },
      {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Hidalgo"
      },
      {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Jalisco"
      },
      {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "México"
      },
      {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "Michoacán"
      },
      {
        "id": 17,
        "name": "Morelos"
      },
      {
        "id": 18,
        "name": "Nayarit"
      },
      {
        "id": 19,
        "name": "Nuevo León"
      },
      {
        "id": 20,
        "name": "Oaxaca"
      },
      {
        "id": 21,
        "name": "Puebla"
      },
      {
        "id": 22,
        "name": "Querétaro"
      },
      {
        "id": 23,
        "name": "Quintana Roo"
      },
      {
        "id": 24,
        "name": "San Luis Potosí"
      },
      {
        "id": 25,
        "name": "Sinaloa"
      },
      {
        "id": 26,
        "name": "Sonora"
      },
      {
        "id": 27,
        "name": "Tabasco"
      },
      {
        "id": 28,
        "name": "Tamaulipas"
      },
      {
        "id": 29,
        "name": "Tlaxcala"
      },
      {
        "id": 30,
        "name": "Veracruz"
      },
      {
        "id": 31,
        "name": "Yucatán"
      },
      {
        "id": 32,
        "name": "Zacatecas"
      }
    ];
    var $select = $('#estados');

    //alert(options);
    $.each(temp, function(id, name) {
      $select.append('<option value=' + name.id + '>' + name.name + '</option>');
    });
  });
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <select name="estados" id="estados"></select>


</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias funcionó, pero como supiste que name es el nombre de mis variables y no temp.loqueseaquetemptenga ??

Comment: Porque asi funciona `$.each()`.  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: mmm creo que lo confundiste al poner "name" como parámetro en el each. En ese caso con "name" se refiere al elemento que está recorriendo en ese momento de la iteracion. Podría ser "obj", "element", "elm" o lo que sea y seguiría funcionando.  Por eso luego usa "`name.name`". Puedes leer la [documentación](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) para entender bien como funciona.

Comment: Yo no lo puse, lo puso el, por eso le explique lo que la variable `name` representa.  Pero si tienes razon, normalmente se utilizan esos nombres.

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias! Tu solución me ha servido

Yo lo tenia de la siguiente manera:

```
[{"id_departamento":"1","0":"1","codigo_depar":"54","1":"54","nombre_depar":"NORTE DE SANTANDER","2":"NORTE DE SANTANDER","id_pais":"2","3":"2","codigo_combi":"541","4":"541","estado_depar":"ACT","5":"ACT","fecha_crea":"2020-06-08 10:58:04","6":"2020-06-08 10:58:04"}]
```

y lo envie al Select de la siguiente manera:

```
var $select = $('#estados');

            $.each(respuesta, function(id, name) {
                $select.append('<option value=' + name.id_departamento + '>' + name.nombre_depar + '</option>');
            });
```

no estoy seguro si es la adecuada pero me funciono.